# User.IsInRole() always false in middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I got a simple middleware class:

```
    public class RouterMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RouterMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (!context.User.IsInRole("Guest"))
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
            return;
        }

        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/home/") 
            || context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/profile/")
        {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/home/");
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

And `context.User.IsInRole("Guest")` returns false for any role in any case.
Are there any ways to check user role in middleware class?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs485fwh(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in `Startup.cs`. Order of middlewares was:

```
        app.UseMiddleware<Middleware.RouterMiddleware>();
        app.UseAuthentication();
```

but has to be:

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMiddleware<Middleware.RouterMiddleware>();
```